# GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER -- obtain triangles emitted from Geometry Shader

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to read the triangles emitted from a geometry shader? I am querying the number of primitives created, and it's the right number. I just don't know how to obtain those primitives.

My geometry shader code take in points, and emits a triangle_strip. I tried copying the geometry shader code to this post, but it was too long -- it gave me a code to content ratio error. The code is at: https://github.com/sjhalayka/julia4d3/blob/master/Release/points.gs.glsl

The C++ code is:

```
        glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

        GLuint array_buffer_vbo, feedback_buffer_vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &array_buffer_vbo);
        glGenBuffers(1, &feedback_buffer_vbo);

vector<float> in_data((fsp.resolution - 1)* (fsp.resolution - 1) * 5 * 9, 0.0f);


        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, array_buffer_vbo);
//      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, in_data.size() * sizeof(float), &in_data[0], GL_STATIC_READ);

        glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, feedback_buffer_vbo);
//      glBufferData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, out_data.size() * sizeof(float), &out_data[0], GL_STATIC_READ);

        GLuint query;

        glGenQueries(1, &query);

        glBeginQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED, query);

        glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, num_vertices);
        glEndTransformFeedback();

        glEndQuery(GL_PRIMITIVES_GENERATED);

        GLuint primitives;
        glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &primitives);

        printf("%u primitives written!\n\n", primitives);

        vector<float> out_data(primitives * 9);

        //glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, out_data.size() * sizeof(float), &out_data[0]);
        glGetNamedBufferSubData(feedback_buffer_vbo, 0, out_data.size() * sizeof(float), &out_data[0]);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < primitives; i++)
        {
            size_t feedback_index = 9 * i;

            triangle t;

            t.vertex[0].x = out_data[feedback_index + 0];
            t.vertex[0].y = out_data[feedback_index + 1];
            t.vertex[0].z = out_data[feedback_index + 2];

            t.vertex[1].x = out_data[feedback_index + 3];
            t.vertex[1].y = out_data[feedback_index + 4];
            t.vertex[1].z = out_data[feedback_index + 5];

            t.vertex[2].x = out_data[feedback_index + 6];
            t.vertex[2].y = out_data[feedback_index + 7];
            t.vertex[2].z = out_data[feedback_index + 8];

            triangles.push_back(t);
        }

        glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
```

I'm using OpenGL 4.6.

Comment: How did you set up your transform feedback data in the shader?

Comment: Dear Nicol, thanks for your time. I am not doing anything in particular with the output of the shader -- no out variables, just a triangle strip. The code for the shader is at: https://github.com/sjhalayka/julia4d3/blob/master/Release/points.gs.glsl